# realloc() : invalid next size making p_thread program

Tags: linux, pthreads, realloc, calloc

I am attempting to make a multithreaded program that computes the prime-factor of each input(each input having its own thread). Using realloc or calloc with a int* Name, inputing large numbers or lots of thread {1..100} gives me realloc:invalid size or malloc.c failure. I am not sure if it is a deep pointer issue, but I need an output of such:
./thread {1..10}
1: 
2: 2
3: 3
4: 2 2
5: 5
etc....
10: 2 5

```
 int size = 5;
    int* primeNumbers = (int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    int n = atoi(param);
    //sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    //Add original value to int* primeNumbers for return printing
    primeNumbers[counter] = n;
    counter++;

    while (n % 2 == 0)
    {
            printf("%d ", 2);
            //If max allocated memory is reached, double memory size
            if (counter == size)
            {
                    size = size * 2;
                    primeNumbers = realloc(primeNumbers,size*sizeof(int));
                    primeNumbers[size] = 0;
            }
            primeNumbers[counter] = 2;
            counter++;
            n = n/2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2)
    {
            while (n % i == 0)
            {
                    printf("%d ",i);
                    //If max allocated memory is reached, double memory size
                    if (counter == size)
                    {
                            size = size * 2;
                            primeNumbers = realloc(primeNumbers,size*sizeof(int));
                            primeNumbers[size] = 0;
                    }
                    primeNumbers[counter] = i;
                    counter++;
                    n = n/i;
            }
    }




enter code here
```

Comment: This means you have heap corruption. Run your program with valgrind and it will probably tell you exactly where you're corrupting the heap. Otherwise, be very careful not to access memory you didn't allocate. I can see two places already where you access memory you didn't allocate.

Comment: The statement `primeNumbers[size] = 0;` (after realloc) is causing the heap corruption. Array indexing is zero-based so this clobbers the slot just past the end of the re-allocated space.